# Constructing jQuery selector with class and var

Tags: jquery, tabs

I've got this ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/" + filmID + ".json?apikey=[your_api_key],
    success: dataHandler,
    crossDomain: true
});
```

**`filmID`** here is a `var` which picks the film's `id` based on which tab is clicked. Then I've got this function `dataHandler()`.

```
function dataHandler (data) {
    $(".title").append(data.title);
};
```

The problem is now it doesn't matter on which tab I click, only that tab's data is loaded. If I try to click on other tab, it doesn't work. I know it has something to do with this title class, because all tabs have it. I need to somehow separate it with maybe adding **`filmID`** to the class so browser knows which data should it load. But I'm kind of lost how to do it and put everything in one string?

Comment: we're even more lost, as we have no idea what your tabs look like, and how we're supposed to seperate them ?

Comment: Your missing the closing `"` at **URL**.

Comment: who is calling `dataHandler `

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

HTML markup:

```
<div class="tab" id="film1">...</div>
<div class="tab" id="film2">...</div>
<div class="tab" id="film3">...</div>
```

Js:

```
$('.tab').click(function(){

    var tab = $(this),
        filmID = tab.attr('id');

    var xhr = $.ajax ({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/" + filmID + ".json?apikey=[your_api_key]",
        crossDomain: true
    }); 

    xhr.done(function(data){
        tab.append(data.title);
    });

});
```